# xCode - @IBInspectable how to add a color field

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview

I want to create a UIView global extension in iOS such that all the UIView's in interfacebuilder will have a runtime attribute to change the color.  I know a view already has a attribute to change the color but mine will be called germanyColor and only work for germany thats why i want another IBInspectable created.

here is my UIView extension so far which does it compile as i get an error that CALayer does not have a color attribute:

```
   extension UIView {
@IBInspectable var germanyColor: CGFloat {
    get {
        return layer.cornerRadius //how can i get this to set a color instead ?
    }
    set {
        layer.cornerRadius = newValue
    }
}
```

}

my end goal is to have a germanyColor option for every UIView element in interfaceBuilder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bunch of issues with your code:

1. You can't create a stored property in an extension, therefore you have to subclass `UIView` to have your extra `germanyColor` property.
2. UIView's `layer` does not have a property named `UIColor` so you can't use it - that's why you code doesn't compile (although it has multiple other problems..)
3. as @matt pointed out - do not call a property with a name that is it's type.